# Issue with saveRDS

Tags: r

I exhibited a strange behaviour of saveRDS whilst resaving an object. Here is a reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2), b = c(3,4))
saveRDS(df, "test.rds") 
readRdsFile <- readRDS("test.rds")
saveRDS(df1, "test.rds") #trying to resave the object however there is an issue with the object df1. Mistaken object name or it has not been compiled somewhere in the code before so it does not exist.
readRdsFile2 <- readRDS("test.rds") #the original file is corrupted.
```

> Error in readRDS("test.rds") : error reading from connection

Does this make sense? Is it intended and is there anything I can do to avoid having the file corrupted?

Comment: it is reproducible... df1 is a data frame which does not exist and the original file gets corrupted

Comment: yes it is, but you may want to remove the line `... #some code goes here` as it may make one think that df1 was defined there

Comment: it is really strange... here's a messy fix : `save_wrapper <- function(object,file){str(object);saveRDS(object,file)}`

Comment: it will return an error for str, before getting to saveRDS, so you won't have the corruption issue

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, post as answer?

Comment: This is definitely a bug.

Comment: @nicola I also think so, but where should I report it? It is part of base R.

Comment: The problem is, that `saveRDS(...)` opens the file for writing without testing wether the object exists or not. Opening a file for writing means destroing the old content (... and in the case of `saveRDS()` put some information, e.g. the magic, at the beginning of the file).

Comment: @deann See here: https://www.r-project.org/bugs.html

Answer (score 2):

*Edit : 2 years later I cannot reproduce this error with R 3.6, so my suggestion to fix this is to update R. Anyone who can reproduce the error please post your R Version as a comment.*

---

I don't know where the problem comes from, but in case you don't find anything better, here's a fix. It will return an error for str, before getting to saveRDS, so you won't have the corruption issue

```
saveRDS2 <- function(object,file){str(object);saveRDS(object,file)}
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2), b = c(3,4))
saveRDS2(df, "test.rds") 
readRdsFile <- readRDS("test.rds")
saveRDS2(df1, "test.rds") # error as df1 doesn't exists
readRdsFile2 <- readRDS("test.rds") #the original file is not corrupted and can be reloaded
```

Comment: Using `str` seems quite random to me and it would also produce some output when the object _is_ found. Perhaps one could check something like `"df1" %in% ls()` before saving

Comment: with exists I need the name of the variable in a string

Comment: You can use `force` as well

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper You are right, my bad. Also `force` can be used, so the evaluation of `df1` is made before the call to `saveRDS`. And guess `saveRDS` should have `force(object)` on top (or something similar, just to see if the object exists).