# Why can I not work with RDS files after saving?

Tags: r, raster, r-raster, rdata

I processed a rasterstack and saved it as `RDS file`. I work in R projects and in case anything is changing in working directories or so, I include the full path while saving a rds. I work on the same computer and same directory, however I realized a few days later, that the saved rds is useless due to missing temporary file R creates when saving it.

Also I would like to be able, to save an rds file, say on RStudio Server and then use it on my local machine and vice versa.

How can I manage, that the actual file is saved in a proper environment or folder, so I can use it also later or even other persons on different machines?

I found a very similar thread to my problem but not a real solution ([Issue with saveRDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456298/issue-with-saverds)).

Here is a minimal example

```
dir<- list.dirs(path="C:/mypath/")
sin<-lapply(1:length(dir), function(i){
       re<-list.files(dir[i], full.names=TRUE)
    })`

sin<-lapply(1:length(sin), function(f){
       re<-stack(sin[[f]])
      })
saveRDS(sin, "C:/mypath/temp_sinlist.rds")`
```

Now everything seems fine. But opening a session later on or even using the file on a different machine; this happens:

```
myrasterstack <- readRDS("C:/mypath/temp_sinlist.rds")
```

it looks alright when I call

```
myrasterstack`

> class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 13061, 13271, 173332531, 5  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent      : 379185, 777315, 523185, 915015  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=37 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names       : LC08_L1TP_201602_01_T1_B10_TIR, LC08_L1TP_201602_01_T1_B11_TIR, LC08_L1TP_201602_01_T1_B02_BLUE, LC08_L1TP_201602_01_T1_B03_GREEN, LC08_L1TP_201602_01_T1_B04_RED 
min values  :                          17343,                          16761,                            6845,                             5941,                           5525 
max values  :                          45672,                          37158,                           65535,                            65535,                          65535
```

But truth is, the file is not actually present:

```
plot(myrasterstack)

> Error in file(fn, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(fn, "rb") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8mDPNi\raster\r_tmp_2018-07-31_134754_7296_99375.gri': No such file or directory
```

I don't want to use RDATA instead because of the overwriting issues.

Comment: It looks like RasterStack is saving a link to your data when you use saveRDS instead of saving the actual data. This has happened to me before when a function returns a memory address to the data instead of the data itself. Can you try unstack() before you save? Or can you try saving a standard dataframe using saveRDS and make sure it opens correctly.

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with `raster`, but some objects have a C++-component that is not natively accessible via the typical R saving mechanisms (e.g., `save`, `saveRDS`). The [`raster` docs](http://rspatial.org/sdm/rst/4_sdm_envdata.html) suggest saving data, but not the stack; [another page](http://rspatial.org/spatial/rst/5-files.html#id2) shows `writeRaster`, but that creates a tiff, not an object file. Perhaps you can reach out to the maintainers at their admittedly-hollow [github issues page](https://github.com/rspatial/raster/issues)?

Comment: You can use `attributes(myrasterstack)` to see if any of the objects have "<pointer: ...>"

Comment: @AdamSampson to your first comment: yes exactly thats happening, I didn't know how to describe it. I honestly don't think that unstack() will do the trick (However, I can not reproduce the error right now), but also that would mean I have a huge pile of files saved, which might be not an efficient choice. `attributes(myrasterstack)`has nothing like "pointer", just a bunch of propperties according my rasterfiles and this: `$filename
[1] ""`

Comment: @r2evans The issue I think is more concern of the `base` package function `saveRDS` like Adam mentioned in his comment. The function just creates a connection to my original files and not saving an actual file. writeRaster would be an option if the file would not happen to be so big, processing is a lot faster when working with rds. But I'll get to the issue page, maybe they can maintain it, still I believe this must be a kind off bug for quite some time now.

Comment: What is `stack()` actually doing for you? Is there a reason you can't save sin before you do the stack?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the base function, it is not creating a connection, it just doesn't know about the loose file reference in the `RasterStack`. Does `str(sin)` reveal the filename reference? If so, I suggest a wrapper function can take this raster object, find the file, include its contents in the RDS file, and then extract it as a (temp) file when you read the RDS file (with another wrapper function).

Comment: BTW, code golf: `dir <- list.files(path="...", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE); sin <- lapply(dir, stack)`. It might bite you in the future if you rely on `re <- ...` as the last commend within `lapply`: the fact that R is invisibly returning the value stored in `re` works here, but if (for instance) the last assignment does *not* include all data (e.g., `re[5] <- NA`), then you should explicitly have `re` or `return(re)` as your last statement.

Comment: @r2evans yes it does. It is the path that also shows in the error message: `.@ file    :Formal class '.RasterFile' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ name        : chr "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp8mDPNi\\raster\\r_tmp_2018-07-31_134754_7296_99375.grd´. Thank you for this suggestion, I'm not so familar with functions like the wrapper you suggest. Do you think, you could give me a minimal example on how to implement this technically? I believe I would like to rate this as an answer too.

Answer (score 2):

To make a reproducible example, you can create a RasterStack like this:

```
library(raster)
sin <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
```

A RasterStack (and other Raster* objects), normally point to files on disk (but not via C++ pointers). The reason for this 'virtualization' is that the files used in this domain, are often much too large to read into RAM memory -- as would be standard practice in R. It is therefore a bad idea to save such an object between sessions; although it should work as long as you are on the same machine and the file is permanent (not in the temp folder). Rather, you should save the data as a raster type file, and reuse that. This is a feature, not a bug, as it helps dealing with large files, and avoids making unnecessary copies of these files.

This, instead of `saveRDS`, you should use `writeRaster`. Like this:

```
writeRaster(sin, "temp_sinlist.grd")
```

(or use another file format, as determined by the filename extension).

If you insist on using `rds`, *and* your dataset is relatively small, you can first read all values into memory:

```
sin <- readAll(sin)
saveRDS(sin, "temp_sinlist.rds")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes more sense to wrap around the object and allow you to optionally save it or a `list` of them.

```
RasterStack2list <- function(object, ...) {
  fn <- normalizePath(slot(object, "name"))
  md5 <- tools::md5sum(fn)
  contents <- readBin(fn, raw(1), n=file.info(fn)$size)
  list(object=object, path=fn, contents=contents, md5=md5)
}

list2RasterStack <- function(object, ..., sametempdir=FALSE, overwrite=FALSE) {
  if (! all(c("md5", "object", "path", "contents") %in% names(object))) {
    warning("no 'path' stored, object might be incomplete", call.=FALSE)
    return(object)
  }
  if (sametempdir) {
    dirn <- dirname(object[["path"]])
    if (!dir.exists(dirn)) dir.create(dirn, recursive=TRUE)
  } else {
    dirn <- tempdir()
  }
  fn <- file.path(dirn, basename(object[["path"]]))
  if (!sametempdir) slot(object[["object"]], "name") <- fn
  if (file.exists(fn) && !overwrite) {
    stop("file exists but 'overwrite' not true: ", sQuote(fn))
  }
  writeBin(object[["contents"]], fn)
  outmd5 <- tools::md5sum(fn)
  if (outmd5 != object[["md5"]]) {
    warning("file contents md5 checksum incorrect; expecting ",
            sQuote(object[["md5"]]), ", actually ", sQuote(outmd5),
            call.=FALSE)
  }
  return(object[["object"]])
}
```

Intended use, assuming `sin` is a list of objects:

```
saveRDS(lapply(sin, RasterStack2list), file="somewhere.rds")
# restart R, different computer, something else ...
newsin <- lapply(readRDS("somewhere.rds"), list2RasterStack)
# should be able to plot newsin[[1]], for instance
```

If you need to add functionality, here's the basic premise/breakdown:

- this supports whatever saving mechanism you want, so use `save` or `saveRDS` or perhaps even `jsonlite::toJSON` if you really want;
- this assumes that the only slot that we need to save is `"name"`; if you try this and there are other missing/wrong slots on restoration, you should be able to add steps to preserve them as well;
- I added a `md5` checksum b/c I've been bitten by endian-ness when I was intentionally playing and trying to break things (on another project), so it is highly likely to be unnecessary here (but barely slows things down); and
- the option `sametempdir=` is meant to try to stiff-arm a problem in case the path is hard-coded in the `raster` object. I have no reason to believe it is, but test first on the same computer without this option, and if something fails, try setting `sametempdir=TRUE`. If this latter call works, then these wrapper functions will not support (yet) moving between different computers (that do not share the relevant filesystem).

Comment: BTW: the only reason I have ellipses (`...`) in the function formals is that the first versions actually *called* `saveRDS` and `readRDS`, in which case other arguments were passed on to those functions; once I saw you wanted to save a list of objects, it made more sense to generalize it a bit and allow you to do the saving yourself (and with whatever serializer you wanted).

Comment: If there is sufficient interest, these functions could be further generalized to accept as an argument a list of candidate slots to check; if the slot name(s) exists, `is.character`, and the file exists, it could embed any and all of them. It's still a bit pigeon-holed need, but not hard. A virtual beer might entice me to do this refinement ...

Comment: @usel, if this (or the other) answer meets your needs, please "accept" one of them.

Comment: The the AC who just downvoted me: I'm fine with disagreement, can you tell me what you found counter-productive, unuseful, unfulfilling, or otherwise worthy of the equivalent of blowing a raspberry at my answer?